# What is the memory limitation for JNI in Android?

Tags: android, java-native-interface, android-memory

I heard that there is no memory limitation PER APPLICATION for JNI in Android.
Then how can I find the limitation for memory in JNI in Android?
I assume it would be relative much larger, of course, still depending on how many applications are running, how much memory has been used in JNI.

I will do some image processing in JNI, and I do not like outofmemory exception.
How can I avoid it?

Comment: I'm curious where did you hear that.

Comment: The memory limitation is probably "as little as possible".

Comment: @Glenn: "How to work around Android’s 24 MB memory limit": http://blog.javia.org/how-to-work-around-androids-24-mb-memory-limit/

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to know the memory limitation in JNI. Try to allocate the memory you need, if return null that means no memory available. if you wanna do image processing, you have to decode image first. limit your bitmap size(width, height), otherwise you will run out of your memory. You'd better cache image data for re-use. Don't keep lots of bitmap in memory. Recycle useless bitmap to increase available memory. Be careful to control your memory, you won't meet out of memory exception.

Comment: Thanks. I think a rough estimation would be good for me to design my image processing algorithm.

Comment: You can pre-allocate a big memory, like a memory pool. then use the memory pool to manage your bitmap. If you can estimate the size of your total memory, you won't have any problem about memory limitation.

Comment: Thanks. I once thought of this way: allocate a big memory; if it fails, allocate a little less memory; if it fails, .... Ultimately, find the available amount of memory. Based on that, I will design my image processing algorithm. Is this what you meant?

Comment: No. I was just asking around to see a better pratice. :) Will try it later.